# Storing website temporary data in an array?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, web

I am making a website with nodejs and mongodb which records the username of the currently online users. I wonder whether it would be better practice to store this in an array created during the website's runtime or should I store it in a database?

Comment: It depends on the project requirement. If the online users information needs to available across server restarts, use database else keep it in memory. Also, if kept in memory, if size of the can grow indefinitely & could exceed the size of RAM, store in database.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with explorer. Generally, when an app is in production, you store information in some sort of database. This insures that your application uses the least possible RAM, assuming that you write decent code. Also, if your application crashes for some unforeseen reason, you can recover quickly and your data isn't lost.